# In Vim, can I format a whole file and end with the cursor where it started?

Tags: vim

I set up this mapping in my .vimrc and it works great...

```
" Auto indent entire file
nmap <C-f> gg=G
imap <C-f> <ESC>gg=G
```

However, after the operation the cursor has moved to line 1, column 1.

Is there a way to do it so that if I'm in the middle of the file somewhere the cursor will remain where it is?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/7086402

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, use marks (`:help mark`):

```
nmap <C-f> mtgg=G't
imap <C-f> <ESC><C-f>
```

Before executing `gg=G`, the current cursor position is saved to mark `t`. After the operation, `'t` jumps back to the mark.

Comment: Or more elegant, `:nnoremap <c-f> 1G=G\`\``.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> is good for walking back through the jump list.  <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> will move you back to the last line in the jump list (or <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> to go back to the last line and column).

Unfortunately, there isn't an "entire buffer" text object, so `gg=G` requires moving back two places in the jump list.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `ma` to mark the current position in buffer `a`, and after the transformation use ``a`(i.e.`backtick`+`a`) to return to that position ? [Here's an article](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/54159) on using marks to move around.

Comment: The regular quote character ' also works and is easier to type than the backtick

Comment: Using ' to return to a mark only brings you back to the line of the mark.  ` will bring you back to the line and column of the mark.

Answer (score 2):

Brian's solution above will work for a macro, but as a good tip, note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> will go to the previous cursor position in the jump list. So if you ever do an operation that moves away, you can step back to a previous position.

Answer (score 1):

As jamessan wrote, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> jumps back to the last posistion in the jumplist. After calling gg=G, this has to be called twice.

Thus, you can use a mapping without marks:

```
map <silent> <C-f> gg=G<C-o><C-o>
imap <silent> <C-f> <Esc> gg=G<C-o><C-o>
```