# Indenting entire file in Vim without leaving current cursor location

Tags: vim, indentation, vi

I already know that `gg=G` can indent the entire file on Vim. But this will make me go to the beginning of the file after indent. How can I indent the entire file and maintain the cursor at the same position?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646850/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See `:h ''`

This will get you back to the first char on the line you start on:

```
gg=G''
```

and this will get you back to the starting line *and* the starting column:

```
gg=G``
```

I assume the second version, with the backtick, is the one you want.  In practice I usually just use the double apostrophe version, since the backtick is hard to access on my keyboard.

Comment: Awesome. The second version is what I was looking for. The only negative point is that the current line will be at the end of the screen then.

Comment: Great.  Try adding a `zz` if you want to reposition line at middle of screen:  `gg=G``zz`

Comment: That keeps the screen unchanged: `mqHmwgg=G\`wzt\`q`. Note it uses `q` and `w` marks.

Comment: @FábioPerez "The only negative point is that the current line will be at the end of the screen then." - This seems to be the middle line in Vim 9. Hello from 2022, ha ha

Comment: btw, what is the advantage of using two backticks instead of `<C-O><C-O>`?

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your .vimrc

```
function! Preserve(command)
  " Preparation: save last search, and cursor position.
  let _s=@/
  let l = line(".")
  let c = col(".")
  " Do the business:
  execute a:command
  " Clean up: restore previous search history, and cursor position
  let @/=_s
  call cursor(l, c)
endfunction
nmap <leader>> :call Preserve("normal gg>G")<CR>
```

You can also use this on any other command you want, just change the argument to the preserve function. Idea taken from here: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tidying-whitespace/

Comment: Replace all of the lets at the beginning with `let w = winsaveview()` and the let and call at the end with `call winrestview(w)` and you restore even the scroll position.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a bookmark for the current position with the m command followed by a letter. Then after you run the indent command, you can go back to that bookmark with the ` (backtick) command followed by the same letter.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar spirit to Alex's answer I use the following mapping in vimrc.

`nnoremap g= :let b:PlugView=winsaveview()<CR>gg=G:call winrestview(b:PlugView) <CR>:echo "file indented"<CR>`

by pressing `g=` in normal mode the whole buffer is indented, and the scroll/cursor position is retained.

Answer (score 1):

Following on top of [Herbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76434/herbert-sitz)'s solution, the reader can also use `<C-o>`

In vim script

```
exe "norm! gg=G\<C-o>"
```

Or mapping

```
:nnoremap <F10> gg=G\<C-o>
```